# List every way to log and access the query,latency and returned data size information from MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql, api-design

So I'm thinking of writing some metrics infrastructure for MySQL and in this particular case I need to get the query along with latency and size returned data. I don't care about insert or functions just queries. Is the [post-parse plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/plugin-types.html#query-rewrite-plugin-type) path the best path ? Is the [general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) a better fit? Should I abandon any attempt like this and put this kind of logging on the client side(hopefully not)?

I'm not married to MySQL if this is simpler in another major SQL implementation. I'd love to know.

Edit: Thanks dan I'm working through the performance data looks interesting.
tadd: I've reformatted the question. I think a request for all of the possible ways removes the need to consider my design concerns.

Comment: This is off-topic here as it requires us to evaluate your requirements, which can be pretty arbitrary, and there's no "correct" answer, just shades of applicable. Try something and see how it goes. A quick prototype is often far more illuminating than the advice of random strangers.

Comment: If you're feeling ambitious, try writing a [MySQL binary protocol proxy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html) that does the metrics for you at that level. Writing a plugin is probably more challenging as you have to operate inside the server itself.

Comment: Rather than a RPC call, how about using some of the existing performance schema elements to fetch this data as required?